# std::string == operator not working

Tags: c++, string, stl

I've been using std::string's == operator for years on windows and linux. Now I am compiling one of my libraries on linux, it uses == heavily. On linux the following function fails, because the == returns false even when the strings are equal (case sensitive wise equal)

```
const Data* DataBase::getDataByName( const std::string& name ) const
{
         for ( unsigned int i = 0 ; i < m_dataList.getNum() ; i++ )
         {
                if (  m_dataList.get(i)->getName() == name )
                {
                         return  m_dataList.get(i);
                }
         }

         return NULL;
}
```

The getName() method is declared as follows

```
virtual const std::string& getName() const;
```

I am building with gcc 4.4.1 and libstdc++44-4.4.1.

Any ideas? it looks perfectly valid to me.

Paul

Comment: just a quick note:

std::string tmpStr1 = name;
std::string tmpStr2 = m_dataList.get(i)->getName() ;

if ( tmpStr1 == tmpStr2 ) ...

This works fine as expected.

Comment: getName returns a reference.  Is the reference still valid?

Comment: Imposable to tell what is wrong with the given code. The error is elsewhere. What about the code for Data::getName(). Another posability is that you overrode the operator==() accidentally have you tried stepping into it to make sure that you are using the standard implementation?

Comment: @Aprogrammer, please add an answer that expands on your comment.  It's probably the correct answer but others may not see it with out an example.

Comment: I think that Paul's comment rules out simple stale references. Comparing copies of the objects should work the same as comparing the objects. This sounds like some kind of compiler or library bug. My advice would be to turn on debugging, try to reproduce, and single-step through the library if so. If not, put on some gloves and try to track down what optimization triggers it.

Comment: Does  !strcmp(m_dataList.get(i)->getName().c_str(), name.c_str()) == 0 work?

Comment: Does this *always* fail or intermittently?   Does it fail with specific sub-classes of the type that your virtual getName() is defined on?

Answer (score 2):

I could hardly see any problem with your code. It seems that the origin of the bug is elsewhere.

I guess that you return the reference of a local variable.

See my example:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::string;

const string& getString()
{
    string text("abc");
    return text;
}

int main() {
    string text("abc");
    std::cout << (getString() == text ? "True" : "False") << "\n";
    return 0;
};
```

Output on my machine:

```
False
```

However I experienced in some environments the excepted output. It is an invalid code, but the behavior is not defined. Apparently, often it works correctly.

Watch out for the compilation warnings like:

```
a.cpp:7: warning: reference to local variable ‘text’ returned
```

You may also try to compile your code with option "-Wall" and see whether warning indicate any real problems.

Answer (score 1):

(Shot in the dark here as I don't see anything wrong with your code sample)

Perhaps your equality operator is being overloaded elsewhere?  Aside from stepping through the code to see, one other way is to explicitly call the equality operator you're trying to reach from std::.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    const std::string lhs = "hello";
    const std::string rhs = "hello";

    if (lhs == rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "Matches" << std::endl;
    }

    if (std::operator==( lhs, rhs ) == true)
    {
        std::cout << "Matches 2" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Should output:

```
Matches
Matches 2
```